# Upgrade Shimano Sora shifters to 105

Tags: derailleur, shimano, shifter

I want to upgrade my 3x9 Sora shifters to 3x10 105s.  However, looking at the [Shimano Compatibility Chart](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8657/3497), it appears to indicate that I'll have to replace my front and rear derailleurs in addition to the cassette, which I knew I'd have to replace.  But I'm not sure I'm reading that chart correctly.

The bike currently has a Shimano Sora bottom pull front derailleur and a Shimano Tiagra rear derailleur.  Can I get by with just replacing the cassette?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posed a similar question (or at least a question which raises similar issues) on here a few months ago: [Moving tfrom Shimano 9- to Shimano 10- speed](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13294/upgrade-shimano-from-9-to-10-speed)

The issue is not the different Shimano ranges per se, its going from 9 to 10 speed.

You can imagine that the 10-speed shifters will be expecting a 10-speed cassette at the other end of the wire - these things are indexed after all.

The other complication in going from a 9- to 10-speed cassette is the chain. You'd need a new, slimmer one. And unfortunately this means a new real derailleur too. Strictly speaking, this again knocks on to the front derailleur. And the chainrings. But as regards the front setup, I was advised that I should be able to get by with my existing setup.

Unless you specifically want to go to 10-speed, you may have some luck doing what I did - jump over 105 altogether and head for the old Ultegra 6500 range.....which was 9-speed. I suspect if you could find shifters from this range, it would do the trick. Alternatively you could go not quite as far and upgrade to Tiagra - I believe the current Tiagra range is now 10-speed, but its not so long ago that it was 9-speed. (The bike I raised my question about was a 2011 model.) Obviously Ultegra will give you better quality but you'll still find Tiagra shifters a noticeable step up from Soras.

If you really do want to go to a 10-speed 105 setup, well I think I costed it as something like GBP400 or more...not a lot less than buying the whole 105 groupset (which can be bought as a single product). But I seem to remember the biggest single cost was the shifters, so take that as an indication.

Comment: Good info, thanks.  And yeah, I checked and the biggest cost in a groupset is the shifters, which is all I really want to upgrade.  I can live with everything else.

Comment: on eBay now (US seller): [http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SHIMANO-ULTEGRA-6510-FLIGHTDECK-STI-SHIFTERS-BRAKE-SET-6501-6500-GLOBAL-SHIP-/200908198833?pt=Cycling_Parts_Accessories&hash=item2ec70fd3b1](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SHIMANO-ULTEGRA-6510-FLIGHTDECK-STI-SHIFTERS-BRAKE-SET-6501-6500-GLOBAL-SHIP-/200908198833?pt=Cycling_Parts_Accessories&hash=item2ec70fd3b1)