# How do I replace road shift levers?

Tags: mechanical, replacement

How do I remove my old (Shimano Sora) brake/gear levers and replace them with new (Shimano 105 5800) levers?

([This is the bike if you want to know more components details](http://www.evanscycles.com/products/specialized/allez-sport-triple-2010-road-bike-ec019408)).

*As a note, I'm asking about step-wise instructions on the technique/method, not technical issues like going from 9- to 11-speed as covered here ([Upgrade Shimano Sora shifters to 105](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14959/upgrade-shimano-sora-shifters-to-105))*

Comment: Posting a few similar questions like this today. I'm planning a major overhaul and thought it more appropriate, and useful to other users, to break up the question "How do I completely overhaul all of my components?" in to many smaller questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove cables.
2. Remove bar tape.
3. Roll back lever covers to reveal clamp bolts
4. Loosen bolts and slide off bars.
5. Follow instructions included with the new levers (these should in effect be a well written reversal of steps 1-4.)