# 9-speed to 10 or 11-speed conversion

Tags: road-bike, drivetrain

I have a Look KG361 that is built with 9-speed Ultegra. Is it possible to change the drivetrain to 2x10 or 2x11 with this frame?

Comment: Don't do it unless you're really into self-abuse.  9-speed hubs are weird birds.  Consider, among other things, that you would have to get new brifters, and non-V-brake brifters are getting hard to find.

Comment: @DanielRHicks do road brifters for V-brakes even exist?

Comment: It is possible but not economical.

Comment: Possible double of [9-speed system to 11-speed drivetrain upgrade?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/29398/9-speed-system-to-11-speed-drivetrain-upgrade). See advice on that thread.

Comment: Find a used 11 speed bike in good condition and swap everything over except the frame components?  Don't know that you'd get a lot of benefit from two extra gears.  I ride fine on a 7 speed cassette.

Comment: @Criggie why? New groupsets are sold in shops and there's no real need to waste one frame to build up another.

Comment: @ojs Money.  That way OP could put all the 9 speed stuff on the new frame and have two bikes for approximately similar prices, rather than a nice bike with new stuff and a pile of slightly used 9 speed stuff.  Round here a complete group set is within 10-15% of a new bike with the same groupset, so why not end up with a new frame for a smallish difference in price.  Then his N is 2 :)

Comment: @Criggie you're making a lot of assumptions about budget, whether the 9-speed stuff is slightly used or worn out, whether the OP wants to replace it with slightly used stuff and probably get new bottom bracket anyway. And finally, if you are paying 90% of price of a bike for a groupset, you can get a better price.

Comment: A complete Ultegra group ordered from the UK is around $600, which is much cheaper than an Ultegra-equipped bike. A complete 105 groupset is $400.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Just be prepared to replace every single drivetrain component. If you go 11-speed you will also need a new rear wheel because 11-speed cassette needs a wider freehub body and possibly new brakes because cable pull changed slightly with 11-speed.

The standard advice here is to not do it because the cost will be close to new bike, but Look frames are quite high end and new bike with similar quality frame would be far more expensive than any random Ultegra bike.

Comment: "11-speed cassette needs a wider freehub body " - not true for all cassettes, 11-34 CS-R8000 works with a good old 8-10 speed freehub bodies.

Comment: It's also a MTB cassette and the question was about a road bike.

Comment: When did Ultegra became an mtb groupset?

Comment: Could also ask when did 11-34 become a road cassette. Seriously though, I didn't know they have those in a road groupset.